# How to resolve common-sql with AwsGenericHook error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow, airflow-2.x

HelloAll,

We hace recently upgraded airflow (MWAA) from 2.0.2 to 2.7.2 and I am having issues with some the dags. I am getting and error with "common-sql",to how to resolve this issue.  My requirment package is as follows:

requirment.txt in MWAA

`--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.7.2/constraints-3.11.txt"   apache-airflow-providers-amazon 'apache-airflow-providers-ftp apache-airflow-providers-slack apache-airflow-providers-imap apache-airflow-providers-sqlite apache-airflow-providers-snowflake apache-airflow-providers-mysql snowflake-connector-python snowflake-sqlalchemy slack-sdk pandas boto3 botocore pendulum pytz pytzdata imapclient xlsxwriter pydrive openpyxl cryptography`

Exact Error in airfow dag:

```
` File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql.py", line 167, in _hook     raise AirflowException( 
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: You are trying to use`common-sql`with AwsGenericHook, but its provider does not support it. Please upgrade the provider to a version that supports`common-sql`. The hook class should be a subclass of 
`airflow.providers.common.sql.hooks.sql.DbApiHook`. Got AwsGenericHook Hook with class hierarchy: [<class 'airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.base_aws.AwsGenericHook'>,
 <class 'airflow.hooks.base.BaseHook'>, <class 'airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin.LoggingMixin'>,
 <class 'typing.Generic'>, <class 'object'>]`
```

Code:

```
  process_csv = SnowflakeOperator(
                        task_id=f'process_csv_{table_name}',
                        sql=f'create or replace table "{snowflake__database}"."{snowflake__schema}".{table_name} clone "{snowflake__database}"."{snowflake__schema}".STG_{table_name}',
                        snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_conn_id",
                        retries=0,
                        on_failure_callback=task_fail_slack_alert
                    )
```

Update the code to remove the error

Comment: I believe this is due to defining Snowflake connection with conn type of AWS. Please check that the conn type of `snowflake_conn_id` in Admin->Connections is Snowflake. Also you need to change `SnowflakeOperator` to `SQLExecuteQueryOperator` as `SnowflakeOperator` is deprecated